# How to get a delay in response from a socket in a JAVA program?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

```
inputstream is;

is.read()



{
    perform a function
}
```

write to same socket

i want a delay between reading and writing

Comment: Can you add more details to this question?  As it stands it is hard to understand and is a candidate for closure.

Comment: Is this for testing?  When I want a delay like this it means I haven't thought through what I'm doing; usually it's a (really bad) way to let another thread finish its job before continuing.  But if you're trying to make sure the program on the other end can handle a delay, Peter Lawrey's got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can read() the data and `Thread.sleep(millis);` the amount of time you want to add.

This is only an approximation and a WAN simulator is the best to use for professional testing (and expensive ;)